# Removing commits from a folder inside a branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I have made several changes, inside my branch, to a `properties` folder by mistake. It was committed with changes from several files (including the ones I wanted)

I want to remove all commits from my branch to the `properties` folder. Then I should pull changes from master branch to be up to date.

How is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Your description is slightly ambiguous: are these commits which *only* changed the properties folder, so the commits should be discarded entirely; or are they commits which *include* changes to the properties folder, so that you need new versions of the commits containing only the other changes? knittl's answer assumes the second interpretation.

Comment: yes i want to remove all commits from the properties folder. I should not have touched that folder... I have to revert everything I did there from my branch. I hope I am clear now

Comment: That's not really any clearer, no. A folder doesn't have commits, _the whole repository_ has commits. Those commits might touch _only_ that folder, or _lots of things including that folder_. You can't "remove" half of a commit, so the steps are different.

Comment: yes my commits included changes to various folders that I wanted with changes inside the properties folder as well..

Answer (score 1):

A commit in git is an immutable snapshot of the whole repository, so what you actually need to do here is create *new commits* which contain the changes you *do* want.

The standard tool for doing this is [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), which can be confusing, but is well worth getting to know.

### 1. Make sure your working copy is clean

Whenever you run any commands that will change your working copy - e.g. merge, pull, rebase - you should make sure you don't have any uncommitted changes. Otherwise, you risk those changes either being lost, or being committed somewhere you didn't intend.

```
git status
```

If this shows uncommitted changes, decide if you want them, and commit or discard them. A reasonably safe thing to do if unsure is ["stash" them](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

### 2. Create a backup branch

In case things go wrong, create a new branch preserving the current history, so you know how to get back to it. Running the below will create a branch called "backup-before-rebase" pointing at what you currently have checked out, *but not switch to it*.

```
git branch backup-before-rebase
```

### 3. Find the range of commits you want to edit

The rebase command is going to re-create a series of commits, ending with what you've currently checked out, but it needs to know where to *start*. This can be:

- "main" or "master" or "develop", or whatever the branch is called which you "branched from"
- "HEAD~3", "HEAD~4", etc, where the number is the number of commits back in history you need to go (based on looking at `git log`)

### 4. Start an "interactive rebase"

Take the start point you've decided, and use it as the argument to `git rebase -i`, e.g.

```
git rebase -i main
git rebase -i master
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

### 5. Edit the instructions

git will pop up a text editor (the same one it pops up for entering commit messages). Each line has three things:

- An action, defaulting to "pick"
- A commit hash
- A description, which is just for reference, editing it doesn't do anything

Find the commits you need to change in the list, and change "pick" to "edit".

Now save and exit the editor, and git will start running your instructions.

### 6. Amend the commits

At each commit which you've labelled "edit", git will stop and give you a chance to make changes.

In your case, you want to change the commit to include an unchanged "properties" folder. First, restore the files from a known good copy - "HEAD^" means "the parent of the current commit" which should work here:

```
git restore --source=HEAD^ properties/
```

This will act as though you've just edited all those files, so now we can stage them for commit, but instead of creating a new commit, we **amend** the existing commit:

```
git add properties
git commit --amend
```

Finally, we tell git to carry on with the next step of the rebase:

```
git rebase --continue
```

### 7. Finishing off

Once it gets to the end of the instructions, you'll have a new, rewritten branch. If you already pushed the branch somewhere, you'll need to "force push" it - be careful with this, it will affect anyone else who has pulled or branched from that branch:

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

### If it goes wrong

If you get in a muddle half-way through the rebase, you can "abort" the rebase and start again:

```
git rebase --abort
```

If this doesn't get you where you hoped, you can go back to your backup branch from earlier, by "hard resetting" to it. This discards everything in your working copy, and points the current branch at your backup:

```
git reset --hard backup-before-rebase
```

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER: `git rebase` is an advanced operation and it can be difficult to recover your original commits. Make sure you understand what it does and have a backup!**

Use interactive rebase (`git rebase -i`) to edit your "faulty" commits:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~10 # rebase last 10 commits
```

Change command from "pick" to "edit" for the commits you want to … edit. Then close the editor to start the rebase. Git will now stop at each commit which has command "edit". Fix your changes, e.g. checkout the previous state of your folder (`git checkout HEAD^ -- properties/`, amend your commit (`git commit --amend`), and run `git rebase --continue` to apply the next patches.

Comment: Rebase is destructive? The pre-rebased commits aren’t removed and can be recovered

Comment: which editor you are referring to? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes, if you are aware of the `reflog`, don't gc, don't delete your branch, … I've rephrased the disclaimer

Comment: @csandreas1 the editor that opens when you run `git rebase -i`

Comment: Rather than recommending a backup (which might imply a copy of the whole repo), the simplest suggestion is to run git rebase on a new branch taken from the one you want to edit. The second simplest is to start with "git branch backup", and roll back with "git reset --hard backup" if things go wrong. Both of these make recovering your original commits *really easy*, and although complex, rebase is a powerful tool which I think people should not be put off from using.

Comment: @IMSoP yes, this works until you somehow end up having uncommitted changes, doing `reset --hard` and all your work is lost. That's totally clear to somebody who has been using Git for years, but can be very surprising to newcomers. Having a (full) backup is _always_ a good idea, not only of your Git repositories. We shouldn't educate others to not do backups, because "there is another way to get back your data if you screwed up". I stand by my disclaimer "make sure you understand what it does". (and backups never hurt).

Comment: Maybe, but that's true of a lot of things you do with git - even just switching branches could mess up your uncommitted changes if you're not careful. At some point, you have to understand that and trust that committing to git **is** your backup. Otherwise you end up with a directory called "my-git-repo-2-backup-new", and you've just recreated version control in the worst possible way.

Comment: I have to disagree. Git is not a backup solution, but a source control management system. Having good backups (of your files, of your repositories, etc.) is orthogonal to working with your source code history. Once the rebase is finished and verified to be correct, the backup can be deleted – Better safe than sorry (yes, I am aware that temporary branches can be deleted too. Copying files is still easier than having many similar branches flying around, _IF_ you are not accustomed to Git that is).